# PHP Расхождение многомерных массивов по значению внутри

Tags: php, массивы

Есть два двумерных массива

```
$all = [
    ['id'  => '1', 'typeString' => 'main', 'hidden' => 0, 'priority' => 1],
    ['id'  => '2', 'typeString' => 'pages', 'hidden' => 0, 'priority' => 1],
    ['id'  => '3', 'typeString' => 'test', 'hidden' => 0, 'priority' => 1]
]; 

$installed = [
    ['id'  => '1', 'typeString' => 'main'],
    ['id'  => '2', 'typeString' => 'pages']
];
```

Нужно сравнить два массива по typeString и получить в итоге их расхождение из первого массива. Нужно:

```
$result = [
    ['id'  => '3', 'typeString' => 'test', 'hidden' => 0, 'priority' => 1]
];
```

Comment: а что именно у Вас не получилось? что вызвало проблему? Вы пытались сами решить эту задачу?

Answer (score 3):

Если вы употребили слово "расхождение" то, наверное, читали или частично знакомы с соответствующими функциями пхп? среди них есть и [`array_udiff()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-udiff.php)

```
$result = array_udiff($all, $installed, function($a, $b){
                  return strcmp($a['typeString'], $b['typeString']);   // return $a[...] <=> $b[...]
              });
```

Comment: Да, пытался сделать таким же способом, но с callback функцией не получалось разобраться. Спасибо!